# Matlab ~ linear equation?

Tags: matlab, equation

do any one know how to solve this equation in MATLAB?

```
F_I*cosd(alpha_I) - F_C(cosd(alpha_C)) = 0  
F_I*sind(alpha_I) - F_T_1 + F_C*sind(alpha_C) = 0  
F_T_1*abs(x_F_C-x_T_1) - F_I*sind(alpha_I)*abs(x_F_C-x_F_I) - F_I*cosd(alpha_I)*abs(y_F_C-y_F_I) = 0
```

I KNOW:

> alpha_I | F_T_1 | x_F_C | x_T_1 | x_F_I | y_F_C | y_F_I

I DON'T know (and want to know):

> F_I | F_C | alpha_C

The problem is in F_C*cosd(alpha_C), which are two variables so I don't know what to write in Ax=B matrix in A.

Comment: This is not a linear equation since it contains the `cosd` of an unknown. Consider using nonlinear solver (optimization) routines, like `lsqnonlin`. Do you have the optimization toolbox?

Comment: It would be helpful to write your equation in terms of unknowns `x(1:3)` and knowns `k(1:n)` simplified as much as possible (so `abs(x_F_C-x_F_I)` becomes, say, `k(5)`. It will then be much easier to write the target function to minimize with the solver.

Comment: In your first equation, do you mean `F_C(cosd(alpha_C))` or `F_C*cosd(alpha_C)`

Comment: Sorry of course F_C*cosd(alpha_C).

Comment: I'm not so sure about the _optimization toolbox_ but I'm using the newest matlab. I just want to solve system of three equations witch 3 variables. That can't be so hard, would it?
For the 'abs(x_F_C-x_F_I)' I can write '476' etc. It's a length from a point to another point. I'm trying to solve this: http://songokussj4.abonas.com/screeny/2013-03-24_183955.png

It just came to my mind, what about if I name F_C*sind(alpha_C) = AA and F_C*cosd(alpha_C) = BB and try to solve with variables F_I, AA, AB and _then_ I will somewhat try to solve alpha_C and F_C in AA,AB ?

Comment: Although these are not strictly speaking linear equations, it turns out they can be solved quite easily - see my answer below. It follows the suggestion you are making in your comment quite well, really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third equation contains only one unknown, namely `F_I`. You can therefore explicitly solve for that, which leaves you with only two equations and two unknowns:

```
F_I= (F_T_1*abs(x_F_C-x_T_1)/(sind(alpha_I)*abs(x_F_C-x_F_I)+cosd(alpha_I)*abs(y_F_C-y_F_I))
```

Now your first two equations are basically of the form

```
a*sind(b)=c
a*cosd(b)=d
```

With a, b unknown. Divide them to get

```
tand(b) = c/d
```

This gives you b (alpha_C), and now solving for a (F_C) is trivial.

Comment: Thank You very much! :-) I totally forgot about goniometric functions and the ability to solve it with it. Thank you :-)